# Cross compiling Boost for ARM on Windows

Tags: boost, cross-compiling

I'm building Boost inside Intel's MINGW shell for ARM on Windows 10.

I've run ./bootstrap and configured project-config.jam with `using gcc : arm : arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ ;` but when I run

```
./b2 --build-dir=/tmp toolset=gcc-arm stage
```

I have this error:

```
User@UserLaptop MINGW64 /c/my/Work/SoftwareTest/boost_1_61_0
$ ./bjam install toolset=gcc-arm --prefix=./lib
/cygdrive/c/my/Work/SoftwareTest/boost_1_61_0/tools/build/src/tools/gcc.jam:84: in gcc.init from module gcc
error: toolset gcc initialization:
error: provided command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++' not found
error: initialized from project-config.jam:12
/cygdrive/c/my/Work/SoftwareTest/boost_1_61_0/tools/build/src/build/toolset.jam:43: in toolset.using from module toolset
/cygdrive/c/my/Work/SoftwareTest/boost_1_61_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam:1052: in using from module project-rules
project-config.jam:12: in modules.load from module project-config
/cygdrive/c/my/Work/SoftwareTest/boost_1_61_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:249: in load-config from module build-system
/cygdrive/c/my/Work/SoftwareTest/boost_1_61_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:412: in load-configuration-files from module build-system
/cygdrive/c/my/Work/SoftwareTest/boost_1_61_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:524: in load from module build-system
/cygdrive/c/my/Work/SoftwareTest/boost_1_61_0/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:295: in import from module modules
/cygdrive/c/my/Work/SoftwareTest/boost_1_61_0/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build from module
/cygdrive/c/my/Work/SoftwareTest/boost_1_61_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
```

But arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ can be found in the $PATH:

```
User@UserLaptop MINGW64 /c/my/Work/SoftwareTest/boost_1_61_0
$ which arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
/c/intelfpga/18.1/embedded/ds-5/sw/gcc/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's Windows in project-config.jam gcc should be specified with extension arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++**.exe** not arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.